# Vagrant: Sync folder with boot2docker box on Windows

Tags: docker, vagrant, rsync, boot2docker, data-synchronization

I try to synchronize a folder with the boot2docker Vagrant box (on Windows 8.1):

**Vagrantfile**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.hostname = "docker-host"
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/boot2docker"
  config.vm.synced_folder "./src", "/sync/src"
end
```

**I tried several ways to synchronize the folder:**

If I do not define a type (how to sync), Vagrant uses SMB. So it's like I have written:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./src", "/sync/src", type: "smb"
```

With this configuration mounting fails (I enter the credentials of my Windows account I'm logged in):

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/boot2docker' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Preparing SMB shared folders...
    default: You will be asked for the username and password to use for the SMB
    default: folders shortly. Please use the proper username/password of your
    default: Windows account.
    default:
    default: Username: My Username
    default: Password (will be hidden):
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 2375 (guest) => 2375 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: docker
    default: SSH auth method: password
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
GuestAdditions versions on your host (5.0.20) and guest (4.3.28 r100309) do not match.
The guest's platform ("tinycore") is currently not supported, will try generic Linux method...
Copy iso file C:\Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the box /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
Installing Virtualbox Guest Additions 5.0.20 - guest version is 4.3.28 r100309
mkdir: can't create directory '/tmp/selfgz99220132': No such file or directory
Cannot create target directory /tmp/selfgz99220132
You should try option --target OtherDirectory
An error occurred during installation of VirtualBox Guest Additions 5.0.20. Some functionality may not work as intended.
In most cases it is OK that the "Window System drivers" installation failed.
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Mounting SMB shared folders...
    default: C:/my-project/src => /sync/src
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:

mount -t cifs -o uid=`id -u docker`,gid=`getent group docker | cut -d: -f3`,sec=ntlm,credentials=/etc/smb_creds_d1d75b0a1810a196107486250f8d20f4 //169.254.152.12/d1d75b0a1810a196107486250f8d20f4 /sync/src
mount -t cifs -o uid=`id -u docker`,gid=`id -g docker`,sec=ntlm,credentials=/etc/smb_creds_d1d75b0a1810a196107486250f8d20f4 //169.254.152.12/d1d75b0a1810a196107486250f8d20f4 /sync/src

The error output from the last command was:

mount: mounting //169.254.152.12/d1d75b0a1810a196107486250f8d20f4 on /sync/src failed: Invalid argument

==> default: The previous process exited with exit code 1.
```

If I use

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./src", "/sync/src", type: "nfs"
```

instead, Vagrant still uses *SMB* (same output as before). If I use

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./src", "/sync/src", type: "virtualbox"
```

I get

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/boot2docker' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
The synced folder type 'virtualbox' is reporting as unusable for
your current setup. Please verify you have all the proper
prerequisites for using this shared folder type and try again.
```

If I use

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./src", "/sync/src", type: "rsync"
```

with *vagrant-gatling-rsync* plugin installed

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-gatling-rsync
```

and run in Cygwin (Cmd has no rsync), I get this:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/boot2docker' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 2375 (guest) => 2375 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: docker
    default: SSH auth method: password
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
GuestAdditions versions on your host (5.0.20) and guest (4.3.28 r100309) do not match.
The guest's platform ("tinycore") is currently not supported, will try generic Linux method...
Copy iso file C:\Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the box /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
Installing Virtualbox Guest Additions 5.0.20 - guest version is 4.3.28 r100309
mkdir: can't create directory '/tmp/selfgz95812741': No such file or directory
Cannot create target directory /tmp/selfgz95812741
You should try option --target OtherDirectory
An error occurred during installation of VirtualBox Guest Additions 5.0.20. Some functionality may not work as intended.
In most cases it is OK that the "Window System drivers" installation failed.
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Installing rsync to the VM...
==> default: The machine you're rsyncing folders to is configured to use
==> default: password-based authentication. Vagrant can't script rsync to automatically
==> default: enter this password, so you'll likely be prompted for a password
==> default: shortly.
==> default:
==> default: If you don't want to have to do this, please enable automatic
==> default: key insertion using `config.ssh.insert_key`.
==> default: Rsyncing folder: /cygdrive/c/my-project/src/ => /sync/src
There was an error when attempting to rsync a synced folder.
Please inspect the error message below for more info.

Host path: /cygdrive/c/my-project/src/
Guest path: /sync/src
Command: rsync --verbose --archive --delete -z --copy-links --chmod=ugo=rwX --no-perms --no-owner --no-group --rsync-path sudo rsync -e ssh -p 2222 -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath=C:/cygwin64/tmp/ssh.640 -o ControlPersist=10m -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentitiesOnly=true -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null --exclude .vagrant/ /cygdrive/c/my-project/src/ docker@127.0.0.1:/sync/src
Error: Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:2222' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]

==> default: The previous process exited with exit code 1.
```

Besides that, I tried another boot2docker box

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.hostname = "docker-host"
  config.vm.box = "dduportal/boot2docker"
  config.vm.synced_folder "./src", "/sync/src"
end
```

which results in

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'dduportal/boot2docker' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 2375 (guest) => 2375 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 2376 (guest) => 2376 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: docker
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...


==> default: Waiting for cleanup before exiting...
Vagrant exited after cleanup due to external interrupt.
```

How do I get folder synchonization to run with Vagrant and boot2docker?

Comment: Hasn't the Docker Toolbox replaced the need for boot2docker? Or at least hidden it's usage behind docker machine. I'm not sure I see why you need Vagrant

Comment: rsync is the only method to work on the default b2d box (on windows), but since it's auth is password based, rsync fails to authenticate. it's possible to manually sync folders, have been looking for a workaround for some time though.

Answer (score 0):

My working setup with **dduportal/boot2docker** on windows looks like the following:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.hostname = "docker-host"
  config.vm.box = "dduportal/boot2docker"
  config.vm.provision "docker"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "virtualbox"
end
```

Comment: Declaring the type of the synced folder as `virtualbox` does not help. I still get `Authentication failure`.